# Apport is not creating .crash file for java crashes

Tags: java, apport

I am having issues on production server, It is groovy/grails application and I am using quartz to run many crons.

There is one cron which is when enabled crashes the JVM. I have no idea why. I can't find any crash dumps or any logs.

I found that the JVM is calling `apport` for crash report but `apport` is ignoring it. I read that `apport` also creates `something.crash` file inside `/var/crash` directory but I don't know it is not creating for Java crashes.

Here's the log from `apport.log` file.

```
ERROR: apport (pid 2150) Fri Sep  5 05:29:31 2014: called for pid 2100, signal 11
ERROR: apport (pid 2150) Fri Sep  5 05:29:31 2014: executable: /usr/local/java/bin/java (command line "/usr/local/java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djvmarg=-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -Xloggc:/usr/local/tomcat/logs/gc.log -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/tomcat/endorsed -classpath /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start")
ERROR: apport (pid 2150) Fri Sep  5 05:29:31 2014: executable does not belong to a package, ignoring
```

Please suggest me how to enable crash dump for apport or any other way to find out why java failed.

Let me know if you require any more information.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You installed `java` outside of the package management system?

Comment: Yes, by downloading gzip from Oracle site.

Comment: There's your problem. `apport` only works against packages.

Comment: Okay, then how do I make java not to report to apport and create a crash dump?

Comment: isn't there any way to make apport create a crash report even if it can report it.

Comment: Yes, if you package `java` into a .deb and install it that way. See more [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/261917/apport-support-for-non-ubuntu-packages). Have you turned on logging for Quartz & Groovy/Grails? That might be a better approach. Assumedly it's a Java program causing the problem.