# Is apport/whoopsie only able to report bugs to Ubuntu's system (launchpad?)?

Tags: apport, whoopsie

My company is creating a private package for use with Ubuntu, available from our private `APT repository`.

If a crash dump associated with our package is generated by `apport`/`whoopsie`, and a user responds to the dialog saying they want to report the bug, where does the report go?

Is there a way to specify the bug reporting system that should be used somehow?

What happens if Ubuntu receives a bug report for an unrecognized package?

Answer (score 1):

[The stable version of the dialog](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140379/how-can-i-track-a-bug-that-caused-a-crash-and-was-reported-via-apport-whoopsie) says you can "report the problem," which does **not** mean filing a bug.

The problem reports go to Ubuntu's error reporting system. Bugs go to Launchpad.

According to the answer on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261917/apport-support-for-non-ubuntu-packages):

> You can set a custom crash database in the package-hook for your package. But if your crash database doesn't act like debbugs or launchpad, you will also need to create a custom crash database connector implementation, which doesn't look like it can be done without installing a python file outside of /opt.

Also see [more information about Apport](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport) and [for developers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport/DeveloperHowTo).